# Disposeable for Observer

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

In RxJava 1 subscribing with an Observer returned a Subscription which could be unsubscribed.

In RxJava 2 subscribing with an Observer returns void and no Disposeable. How is it possible to stop that "Subscription"?

```java
// v1
rx.Observable<Long> v1hot = rx.Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
rx.Observer<Long> v1observer = new TestSubscriber<>();
Subscription subscription = v1hot.subscribe(v1observer);
subscription.unsubscribe();

// v2
Observable<Long> v2hot = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observer<Long> v2Observer = new TestObserver<>();
v2hot.subscribe(v2Observer); // void
```

**EDIT**: how to handle the case, where we use an observer which doesn't itself implement `Disposable`, like `BehaviorSubject`? Like in this example:

```java
// v1
rx.Observable<Long> v1hot = rx.Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
rx.Observer<Long> v1observer = rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.create();
Subscription subscription = v1hot.subscribe(v1observer);
subscription.unsubscribe();

// v2
Observable<Long> v2hot = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observer<Long> v2Observer = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(-1L);
v2hot.subscribe(v2Observer); // void
```

Answer (score 10):

[All](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe()) [other](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer)) [subscribe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Consumer)) [methods](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Consumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Action)) [return](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.functions.Consumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Consumer,%20io.reactivex.functions.Action,%20io.reactivex.functions.Consumer)) a [`Disposable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/Disposable.html). In your example, the [`TestObserver`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/TestObserver.html) itself implements `Disposable`, so you can call [`dispose()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/TestObserver.html#dispose()) on the observer itself to dispose of the subscription.

Otherwise you can use [`DisposableObserver`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableObserver.html) as a base class for your own custom observers to have the [`Disposable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/Disposable.html) behavior provided to you by the abstract base class.

**EDIT** to answer the updated question:

In case you need to use the [`subscribe(Observer)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe(io.reactivex.Observer)) method (the one returning void), but you need to use an `Observer` which doesn't implement `Disposable`, you still have the option to wrap your `Observer` in a [`SafeObserver`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/SafeObserver.html) which will provide you with `Disposable` behavior (among other contract conformance guarantees).

Comment: In this specific case that works. But what if it doesn't implement that? Like if its a subject (updated question).

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why they changed that. That's very inconvenient.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's something I can't answer. Maybe the awesome lead developer of RxJava2, [Dávid Karnok](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd) could be able to elaborate on design decisions, but there's no mechanism in SO to notify him so we can only hope he will check on this question, which he does regularily on RxJava related questions.

Comment: Actually, I found this [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscription) on RxJava's GitHub page, which provides some reasoning for the changes: it's mostly for compatibility with the Reactive-Streams spec.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `subscribe(Observer)` you can call `subscribeWith(DisposableObserver)` 
which returns a disposable.